# Facebook FB.ui stream.publish error

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, fbjs

Working on a project that has a website and a Facebook page. They both reference the same SWF file and JS code that the SWF file uses to interact with the website/Facebook.

The custom Javascript action, which invokes the FB.ui() method for sharing, works so much in that the dialog/popup appears, however Facebook results with an error ("An error occurred. Please try again later."). I get this error in all browsers.

Using a stream.share method works fine, however the stream.publish is giving me grief on the website. What's notable is that the exact same code works within Facebook.

I am loading the FBJS SDK through the same methods on both sites (The Facebook page is an iframe that's hosted on the same server) and also loading the scripts for the pages in the same order.

```
function connectFacebook(score) {
    // No score, share link
    if ( score == 0 ) {
        FB.ui({
            method:             'stream.share',
            u:                  'http://www.example.com/'
        });
    // Has score, publish to wall
    } else {
        FB.ui({
            method:             'stream.publish',
            message:            'I scored '+score+' at Game!',
            attachment: {
                name:           'Game',
                caption:        'Game caption',
                description:    'I scored '+score+'! Play and share to win the prize pack!',
                href:           'http://www.example.com/'
            },
            action_links: [
                { text: 'Game', href: 'http://www.example.com/' }
            ],
            user_message_prompt:    'Tell your friends about Game'
        },
        function(response) {
            if ( response && response.post_id ) {
                //alert( 'Post was published.' );
            } else {
                //alert( 'Post wasn\'t published.' );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the error was. When connecting to the FBJS SDK on the website, I had a Page ID entered instead of an App ID.